# Git submodule modified after a git pull, should I push?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have two bare repos `super` and `a`, one clone of `super` - `clone_super` and one clone of `a` - `clone_a`. I've added repo `a` as a submodule in `clone_super`.

If I now make some changes in `clone_a`, push those and do a `git pull origin master` in `~/clone_super/a`, it will render in a `modify status` for `~/clone_super/a`, displayed after `git status` in `~/clone_super`.

If I do `git submodule update`, `~/clone_super/a` will revert to previous commit. So, is it intended that I need to commit and push submodules for repos that they exist in each time I update them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you must commit and push a submodule after you update it.

Think of how the directory would work if it wasn't a submodule, every time you changed a file you would have to commit and push it.  A submodule is exactly the same except **super** does not track the file changes directly.  Instead the repository inside the submodule tracks the file changes and the **super** repository tracks those changes by tracking *commits* in the submodule.

The nice thing about this is it allows tracking at different granularity.  You can make dozens of tracked changes in the submodule without changing the **super** repository and then make a single commit to **super** reflecting the changes in the submodule.  The cost is the requirement of committing twice.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks (to both) for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's intended, it lets you keep in the history which version of repo `a` is using each version of repo `super`